# Immutable data class to mutable

Tags: kotlin, mutable

I have a immutable data class which I use as a standard template. I want to create a wrapper which contains this prototype, but in the process I want to transform the prototype from immutable to mutable. Is there any way one would transform all fields from val to var, and collections from immutable to mutable, without creating duplicate class?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. You should make a separate class or re-think your design. Unless you have hundreds of fields, just create the wrapper with your prototype and use it to initialize your var fields (i.e. var someVar = prototype.someVal). Hard to say without actually seeing your code, though.

Comment: Depending on your use-case you could try the `copy` function of data classes.